# Generate Gsettings schema files in linux

Tags: linux, glib, gsettings

I am using [Gsettings schema](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) and have `com.test.gschema.xml` file. Now some keys inside the schema are enum and thus I require `com.test.enums.xml` file.

Now I am using CMakeLists and thus can't use **gsettings_ENUM_NAMESPACE** and **gsettings_ENUM_FILES**. On searching I found out that we can make use of [glib-mkenums](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/glib-mkenums.html) utility but I tried generating the *.enums.xml file using it by providing it the .c and .h files having the enums declaration and definition but all it does is generate an empty file with no enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glib-mkenums` utility parses C files for enumeration definitions, and can be used to generate other files—typically, C sources for GType enumeration definitions to be used with GObject. The same utility can also be used for generating other file types, like the XML for GSettings schemas.

You can look in the `gsettings.m4` macro file shipped by GLib to get the `glib-mkenums` incantation that the macros generate for you when using Autotools:

```sh
glib-mkenums \
  --comments '<!-- @comment@ -->' \
  --fhead "<schemalist>" \
  --vhead "  <@type@ id=\'$NAMESPACE.@EnumName@\'>" \
  --vprod "    <value nick=\'@valuenick@\' value=\'@valuenum@\'/>" \
  --vtail "  </@type@>" \
  --ftail "</schemalist>" \
  --output $OUTPUT_FILE \
  $INPUT_FILES
```

Where `$NAMESPACE` is the namespace of your library—and would be the `gsettings_ENUM_NAMESPACE` value; `$INPUT_FILES` contains the list of files that define enumeration types to be used as settings values; and `$OUTPUT_FILE` is the XML file you're generating.

I recommend reading the `glib-mkenums` manual page, which lists all the expansions and options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I am using CMake build and I need to invoke the above command. So what will be the values for `@type@` or @valuenick@?

Comment: I tried the above command and it's working. Also `glib-mkenums` figures out the value of all `@...@` from the input files passed to it.